# Как узнать на каком месте строка после сортировки?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица пользователей в PostgreSQL. Делаю топ и нужно реализовать функцию, для определения местап пользователя по рейтингу.

Найти первые 3 места у меня не составило проблем с помощью:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ratedByUsers > 1 ORDER BY rate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $1
```

Где $1 - "Место - 1"

Но вот как мне найти место на котором расположен пользователь зная его id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать оконные функции.

```
select
  users.*,
  rank() over (order by rate desc) as rank
from users
where rate between 20 and 70 -- любые условия фильтрации
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMGvmMtT71rj4pkVZdWVX3/0

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!